# Viewpager dynamic height for all fragment (Like google calendar)

Tags: android, android-fragments, calendar

Maybe I can not explain the problem at title.

I am working on a Calendar Application, Pagination of this calendar are made by ViewPager.
First, I could not arrane the ViewPager's height It filled all page (Wrap content did not work) so I wrote a custom viewpager but a new problem showed up.

As you can see below image, Some months in the calendar have 6 lines but some months have 7 lines in gridview. It is changed according to start of day, total day in month etc.

[image]

I want to enlarge the size of if line number count is 7 or to downsize if line number count is 6. Google calendar can do this.

This is my CustomViewPager below.

```
public class CustomCalendarViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public CustomCalendarViewPager( Context context ) {
        super( context );
    }

    public CustomCalendarViewPager( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super( context, attrs );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec ) {

        super.onMeasure( widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec );

        int height = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++ ) {
            View child = getChildAt( i );
            child.measure( widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( 0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ) );
            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            int leap_space = Math.round( ( h / 4 ) );
            if ( h > height ) height = ( h * 7 ) + leap_space;

        }
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY );
        super.onMeasure( widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec );
    }
}
```

If you want more code, I can edit this question.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

```
calendar_pager.setOnPageChangeListener( new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled( int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels ) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected( int position ) {
                System.out.println( "onPageSelected " + position );
                calendar_pager.requestLayout();
                calendar_pager.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged( int state ) {

            }
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup a [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) on the ViewPager, and in the `onPageSelected` override, call `requestLayout` and `invalidate` to force the pager to re-measure it's height.

Inside `onMeasure`, use the currently selected item to set the height.

Comment: I called requestLayout() and invalidate() functions in onOpageSelected but I don't understan what I will make in onMeasure. I edited my question.

Comment: Basically instead of looping over all the items to get the height, just get the height of the item at index getCurrentItem()

Comment: getCurrentItem() function returns only current position. 

I tried onMeasure() and setMeasuredDimension() methods. I read this => http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html and this => http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html 

Plase can you tell me what I should do in onMeasure(). I have struggled for 4 hours :D

Comment: What I am saying is, instead of a FOR loop inside onMeasure checking all children. Just simply use getChildAt(getCurrentItem()) and measure that. Thats it

Comment: I exactly understand you but It is not working. It throws NullPointerException. Even though It doesn't work, thank you for help.